# Using Core Data to model event detail database

Tags: database-design, core-data

I'm trying to design a database for a car maintenance log using Core Data (iOS 6). The problem I'm facing seems to be in part because id's are built into the model (generated automatically). Let me explain:

I want to create a table something like this:

```
MAINTENANCE_EVENTS
==================

EventType                    LogDate
-------------------------------------------------
Brake Replacement            01/01/13
Oil Replacement              02/01/13
Oil Replacement              08/07/12
```

But I want to provide details in other tables about these events. For example, brake replacement should list the brake manufacturer, oil should list the brand of oil, tyre wear should log whether the tyres were rotated and on which tyre the tread is measured, etc.

How can I link these master entries to other tables using the core data Entity-Relationship model?

Or is the best solution to just add a transformable attribute to MAINTENANCE_EVENTS that holds custom classes for details of each EventType?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit this *But I want to provide details in other tables about these events*? Are they just text descriptions or something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't look at core data in terms of relational Database. Core data is a object graph manager.

You need to create another entity called `EventNotes` and then create a relationship From `Event` to `EventNotes`, name it  "Notes" or something (Mark it as one to one).

And also don't forget to create inverse relationship from `EventNotes` to `Event`

look at this link for core data relationship
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html

Transformable attribute is a bad solution for you requirement. look at this questions answer. 
[When *not* to use Core Data type Transformable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783091/when-not-to-use-core-data-type-transformable)